# Github Actions Failing Error: Fail to load actions/checkout/main/action.yml

Tags: github, github-actions

GitHub Actions used to work until recently. It started with the error coming from uses: `docker/login-action@v1` and error `Fail to load docker/login-action/v1/action.yml`

After resolving this with sepcifiyng the exact version: `docker/login-action@v1.13.0`

I run now into the following error. When I run my actions I get the error:

```
Getting action download info
Download action repository 'actions/checkout@main' (SHA:2d1c1198e79c30cca5c3957b1e3b65ce95b5356e)
Download action repository 'microsoft/variable-substitution@v1' (SHA:6287962da9e5b6e68778dc51e840caa03ca84495)
Download action repository 'docker/login-action@v1' (SHA:dd4fa0671be5250ee6f50aedf4cb05514abda2c7)
Download action repository 'docker/build-push-action@v2' (SHA:ac9327eae2b366085ac7f6a2d02df8aa8ead720a)
Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter ''using: node16' is not supported, use 'docker' or 'node12' instead.')
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.ConvertRuns(IExecutionContext executionContext, TemplateContext templateContext, TemplateToken inputsToken, String fileRelativePath, MappingToken outputs)
   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionManifestManager.Load(IExecutionContext executionContext, String manifestFile)
Error: Fail to load actions/checkout/main/action.yml
```

Here is my CI/CD script:

```
name: build push to CR

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  APP_NAME: proj
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ['self-hosted', 'Linux', 'X64']
    environment:
      name: INT
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Main
      uses: actions/checkout@main
    
    - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
      uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
      with:
        files: './src/Presentation/Prj.Veriy.WebApi/appsettings.json'
      env:
        ConnectionStrings.NpgsqlConnection: ${{ secrets.string }}

    - name: Fetch latest version
      id: fetch_version
      run: echo ::set-output name=TAG::${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}

    - name: Login to ACR
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: ${{ secrets.Reg }}
        username: ${{ secrets.Usr }}
        password: ${{ secrets.Scr }}
    
    - name: Build and push staging images
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        tags: ${{secrets.URL}}/app:latest
        push: true
```

Has anyone came across a similar issue in the recent days?

Comment: Looks like you're self-hosted runner is using an old version of the action runner. If upgrading is not an option for you, you need to manually select versions of your actions that run on node12.

Comment: Unfortunately the GitHub Runner I am using is a Organisation Runner and as I am no admin of the organisation I'll have to reach out to one of the admins. I found a work around for now. Instead of `uses: actions/checkout@main` I am using `uses: actions/checkout@v2`.

Comment: That should work for now, but in a few days/weeks you'll start seeing warnings in your logs telling you that you should start running stuff on node16 ;-) So upgrading the runners is a good idea anyways.

Comment: Good point, is there a way to automatically keep a runner up to date?

Comment: My understanding is that runners do this by default, but perhaps you admins have disabled that.

Comment: @MarcOttenbacher, using uses: actions/checkout@v2 didn't work for me.